# Manipulating a subsection of an image in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have a task where I need to track a series of objects across several frames, and compose the background from the image. The issue arises because one of the objects does not move until near the end, so I'm forced to take a shoddy average of the image. However, if I can blur out the objects, I think I'll be able to improve the background average.

I can identify a subsection of the image where the object is, an m by m array. I just need the ability to blur out this section with a filter. However, imfilter uses a fullsized array (image) as its input, so I cannot simply move along this array pixel by pixel in a `for` loop. But, if I try removing the image to take an image, I cannot put it back in without using another `for` loop, which would be computational expensive.

Is there a method of mapping a blur to a subsection of an image using MATLAB? Can this be done without using two `for` loops?

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
sub_image = original_image(ii:jj,mm:nn)
blurred_sub_image = imfilter(sub_image, etc)
original_iamge(ii:jj,mm:nn) = blurred_sub_image
```

In short, you don't need to use a for loop to address a subsection of an image. You can do it directly, both for reading and writing.